# USB connector to BNC connectors back to USB connector

Tags: connector

I would like to split a USB cable (carrying data from an instrument) up into separate parts, I think there are 4 or 5 connectors inside of it including ground, then send two each through my BNC ports. I have several BNC ports into an apparatus which is hermetically sealed. Would it be a bad idea to do this? I've heard something about possible problems with impedance, but I don't know enough to say if this is a bad idea or not.

Comment: Why not use a [hermetically sealed USB connector](http://www.rhseals.com/usb-a-in-molded-housing/)?

Comment: @Samuel  That's a good idea.  But possibly, the O.P. can't install additional connectors on his hermetically sealed apparatus.  So, he may or may not have a choice of the connector.

Answer (score 1):

If your USB is working at high speed (480 Mbit/sec) rather than full speed (12 Mbit/sec), then yes: trying to split out the cable and run through BNC will give you all sorts of problems. The twisted pair in a USB cable presents a balanced load, while the BNCs do not. Worse, if your BNCs are connected to the bulkhead you'll have to use 2 BNCs, one for each data line. If the BNCs are floating, you can give it a try with both data lines through a single BNC, but be prepared for disappointment.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: All of my information is valid for USB 2.0 and earlier. USB 3.0+ is more complex due to using differential signalling for both a transmit AND receive pair. USB 2.0 and earlier only have a single differential pair.

USB 2.0 and earlier has four wires: +5V, GND, D+, D-. It should be easy to simply split each wire to the center pin of the BNC's if you have four of them. If you only have three BNC's, then you can tie ground to the shield but watch out for ground loops. Though, you might have speed problems if you don't keep your conductors shielded as much as possible.

Buy four BNC cables, one of these: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9966 (Or another type B female breakout board) and one of these: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12700 Chop the BNC cables in half, strip the ends and solder them to their respective signal pins. You might have to shorten the BNC cables if you run into speed problems.

USB is pretty robust. I have used cheap, thin USB cables with removable drives and measured data transfers at around 12MB/s. I then used a longer but high quality cable and then measured 39MB/s. So the cheap cable caused a lot of errors that USB was able to compensate for at the expense of slower data transfers.

YMMV.

Just curious, what type of hermetic enclosure is this? I have worked on Vacuum systems, glove boxes and other systems with hermetic connectors e.g. flight critical hardware, missile parts and satellite components. I have made very simple feedthroughs for glove boxes using a KF flange with a tube, feeding the wires through with a simple plastic support to keep them separated and potting it with epoxy.

Comment: Non 3.x USB has differential data lines, not Rx/Tx. 3.x USB has even more signals.

Comment: Sorry - there is bad / wrong information in this answer.  USB uses differential signalling on the D+ & D- lines.

Comment: @DwayneReid Differential signal or not, splitting them through a pair of coax cables isn't going to mangle the signal that much. It's not like we are using a balun to convert to a single ended signal. Nowhere did I say to tie data- to ground which would violate the differential signalling. Keep the coax short and everything should work. Have you even seen the quality of many so-called USB 2.0 cables? Split coax is a luxury cable compared to much of the junk sold. Besides, modern transceivers are really good at dealing with junky cables.

Comment: You are still missing the point.  USB 1 & USB 2 both use a single PAIR of wires as a differential signalling pair.  There is NOT a TX wire, nor is there a RX wire.  Please correct your answer and I'll happily remove both my comments and the down-vote that I gave to your answer.

Comment: @DwayneReid Doh! That completely slipped passed me. Been working with RS232 lately and had Tx/Rx on the brain.Fixed.